# ionic/npm/node: updating ionic breaks my project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I know it's probably easy to solve, but I am a bit nervous as I am close to delivery (aaaaaaargh, NEVER run an update so close to delivery....)

Always when issuing `ionic serve`, I got a message that there was a new version of `ionic` ready to download.

Yesterday I gave in, and hit

```
npm install -g ionic
```

This went fine.
But now this morning, when issuing `ionic serve` again, I get

```
$ ionic serve
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'colors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    ...
```

I've found issue reports on the web like this one:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/574

but I dare to say it does not apply to my case.
I am using `nvm` on linux, and `which nvm` reports

```
/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin/npm
```

which should be the same as yesterday.

Do I maybe need to run `npm install` in my project directory again?
`node_modules` is there, as is for example the `colors` package.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:
Looks like the installation actually doesn't finish well!

After issuing "npm install -g ionic" again, I get:

```
   ....
    - dezalgo@1.0.3 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
    - realize-package-specifier@3.0.1 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/realize-package-specifier
    - readdir-scoped-modules@1.0.2 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/readdir-scoped-modules
    - read-installed@4.0.3 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed
    - async-some@1.0.2 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/async-some
    - write-file-atomic@1.1.4 node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/write-file-atomic
    /home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib
    └── (empty)

    npm ERR! code 1
    >$
```

That doesn't look good....why would npm stop like this? No error message?
Looks like more of an npm issue to me...

Comment: To my defense, I was having issues with images not showing up when creating the apk, and someone had suggested to update ionic....(The solution was something else)

Comment: have you tried npm install --save colors ?

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik I did. This would work if  `colors` wasn't in `node_modules` - but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember what was the version of ionic that you had before, you could remove ionic:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

and install the old version:

```
npm install -g ionic@1.2.3
```

where `1.2.3` is your version that you want to install.

Alternatively, you can install it not globally but locally and run it as `./node_modules/...` possibly with a symlink in your project's main directory. That way you could have a specific version that is known to work (or a range of versions) specified in your `package.json` file and always know that it is available after `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by installing the latest node version with nvm, and then re-installing ionic....

Not a real solution but solves the problem.